# Dynamically assign directives via an object in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

If I have a component in vue:

```
<template>
    <component v-bind="dynamicAttrs"></component>
</template>
```

And I want to assign some dynamic attributes to it where v-demo is a custom directive:

```
data() {
  return {
    dynamicAttrs: {
      'class': 'foo'
      'v-demo': true
    }
  }
}
```

Although I can see the attbitues in the dom the custom directive is not firing in this scenario.

Is there a way I can dynamically assign directives via an object in vue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-bind` is a directive. You can't apply a directive with another directive

Comment: So how would I dynamically bind directives via an object?

Comment: You can't. It is not possible

Answer (score 2):

It is true what Michael said but maybe you can work around it a bit:

```
<template>
    <component :is="customComponentName" :data="dynamicAttrs"></component>
</template>
```

then you can create a custom component that renders based on the data you put in.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

option 2:

create an custom directive and put the dynamic values in the arguments:

```
<template>
    <component v-demo:[show]="dynamicMethod" :class="{}" />
</template>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Dynamic-Directive-Arguments

Comment: I want to dynamically assign the directive name at run time. So the directive name in this case 'v-demo' could be anything. Which means Option 2 won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do in this manner if you genuinely want this(Just recently, I had the same thing). Although it yikes a little, but it works. If you have more directives, it becomes ugly

```
<template>
  <component class="foo" v-if="hasDemoDirective" v-demo/>
  <component class="foo" v-else/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ComponentWrapper',
  props: {
     hasDemoDirective: {
         type: Boolean,
         default: false
     }
  }
}
</script>
```